# Locatizing Barcode using Scilab with [SVIP toolbox & IPD toolbox loaded]

Tags: image-processing, scilab

I'm new in Scilab and currently working on a project on barcode.

How can I locate barcode in an image of a product?

Is there any clue on what I can research on?

Comment: What else is in the image? Maybe this fits better on dsp.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Okay! I will post it on the forum. Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8999080/1134940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide image into NxM sub-images. Then folow either:

a) Make FFT on each sub-image and compare result with pre-computed 2D FFT of standard barcode image. (Because barcodes are pretty monotone and highly repetitive images they should generate similar FFT patterns)

b) Execute some thining (skeletonization) algorithm to leave only skeletons in images. Then do Radon or Hough transform on each skeleton sub-image and look for bunch of lines which has same deflection angle withing error bounds.

I personally would choose second way with pre-skeletonizing step because Radon/Hough transforms are especially designed for searching lines in images.

Comment: It seem logical but don't know whether will works??
Sorry, I new here!! So I don't really understand the terms! Anyway I will try google it and try!
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the barcode is the only significant thing in the image, you could do a Radon transform and then calculate the RMS of each rotation, and keep the row with the highest value.

Comment: It seem logical but don't know whether will works?? Sorry, I new here!! So I don't really understand the terms! Anyway I will try google it and try! Thanks! :)