# How to find the location of barcode in an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

How can I find the location of barcode in an image?

Original Image
[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the location of barcode, normally differences of gradient method is taken. If we take contrast gradient across a barcode, we get high gradient in horizontal direction while low gradient in vertical direction. So where their difference (ie horizontal gradient-vertical gradient) is maximum, we take position of barcode.

Please refer to these paper: [Reading Barcodes](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aWI1OFyj4XR0J%3ausers.soe.ucsc.edu/~orazio/papers/GalloWACV09.pdf%20uc%20santa%20cruz%20detect%20bar%20code%20gradient&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiSFU4ecQml_4AQCQREbT_COLzQ806ZULcWvwpUr_2678Dzk9mKL43x882JWa4GrrgBvwfJgMRT5HyjY2AN7gxwr06FbLJaqRt3T3-Bhn7RYiUGZiUWtQ852FOW6W5-MTka8luc&sig=AHIEtbTmvsTeUTDFkXyyMNY4vF1qEnfuog)

Following links also deals with this : [Link 1](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/wiki/DetectingBarcodeDetail), [Link 2](http://surf-it.soe.ucsc.edu/node/104)